# Drawing a series of graphs receding into the page; TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

I want to draw a panel of graphs of citation networks receding into the page, as the below sketch demonstrates. In the below sketch, each blue rectangle represents a citation network at a different point in time, drawn as a `tikzpicture`.

I tried adapting [this example of a vertical stack](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/swan-wave-model/). Interchanging the x- and y-commands on that doesn't produce the right effect and so I though there might be a better way. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I show here how to do it with one cobbled together `tikz` image (I don't know how to use `tikz`, so please forgive the incompetence) and use an `\includegraphics` for the rest.  Substitute your code for each `\savestack`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\def\incg{\includegraphics[width=.5in]{graph.jpg}}
\begin{document}
% REPLACE \incg IN NEXT LINES WITH YOUR `tikz` IMAGES
\savestack\layerA{\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\colorbox{white}{\tiny%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [draw] (A) at (0,0) {demo text};
   \node [draw] (B) at (0,-.7) {demo text};
   \draw (A.215) -- (B.145);
   \draw (A.325) -- (B.35);
  \end{tikzpicture}}}}
\savestack\layerB{\incg}
\savestack\layerC{\incg}
\savestack\layerD{\incg}
\savestack\layerE{\incg}
\savestack\layerF{\incg}
\savestack\layerG{\incg}
This sets and staggers the boxes.\\
\fbox{\setstackgap{L}{.06in}\Longunderstack[l]{%
  \kern.6in\layerG\\  
  \kern.5in\layerF\\
  \kern.4in\layerE\\
  \kern.3in\layerD\\
  \kern.2in\layerC\\
  \kern.1in\layerB\\
  \kern.0in\layerA\\
}}

or this\\
\setbox0=\hbox{
\stackinset{r}{.6in}{t}{.36in}{\layerA}{%
\stackinset{r}{.5in}{t}{.30in}{\layerB}{%
\stackinset{r}{.4in}{t}{.24in}{\layerC}{%
\stackinset{r}{.3in}{t}{.18in}{\layerD}{%
\stackinset{r}{.2in}{t}{.12in}{\layerE}{%
\stackinset{r}{.1in}{t}{.06in}{\layerF}{%
  \layerG%
}}}}}}
}\fbox{\kern.6in\raisebox{.36in}{\box0}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Never knew about the stackengine package. Cool.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    box/.style={%
        rectangle,       
        minimum height=4cm,
        minimum width=4cm,
       bottom color=blue,top color=blue!50
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in{4,3,2,1}{
\node[box] (c1) at (\x,\x) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To replace the rectangles with tikzpictures, I would set the node style={draw=none}, and insert a tikzpicture environment inside a minipage as the node text?

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is to stack some `tikzpicture`s, you can avoid nesting `tikzpicture` environments (which could produce undesired results or force you to previously box the inner environments) by simply using `\raisebox`es and some `\hspace`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=orange!30] (0,0) rectangle (2.5,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hspace*{-30pt}\llap{\raisebox{-0.2\height}[0pt][0pt]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill=cyan!30] (0,0) rectangle (2.5,-4);
  \end{tikzpicture}}}%
\hspace*{-30pt}\llap{\raisebox{-0.4\height}[0pt][0pt]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill=magenta!30] (0,0) rectangle (2.5,-4);
  \end{tikzpicture}}}%
\hspace*{-30pt}\llap{\raisebox{-0.6\height}[0pt][0pt]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill=olive!30] (0,0) rectangle (2.5,-4);
  \end{tikzpicture}}}%
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]